# Node js Mongoose encrypt data using mongoose-encryption

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to encrypt my data in mongodb. I'm using mongoose-encryption plugin, but i have an error like this :

"throw new Error('must provide either options.secret or both options.encryptionKey and options.signingKey');"

here's my code:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  profile: ProfileSchema,
  timeStamp: Date,
  created: Date,
  email: {
    type: String,
    sparse: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  }
})

var encKey = process.env.SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING
var sigKey = process.env.SOME_64BYTE_BASE64_STRING

UserSchema.plugin(encrypt, { encryptionKey: encKey, signingKey: sigKey , encryptedFields: ['email']})
```

so, what i'm missing in my code? i have no idea with this error. because i just following steps in [here](https://github.com/joegoldbeck/mongoose-encryption) but failed. i'm new in node and mongoose. please help me... thanks anyway...

Comment: i notice its because of this line:

var encKey = process.env.SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING
var sigKey = process.env.SOME_64BYTE_BASE64_STRING

if i try to change the variable encKey and signKey :

var encKey = 'a2V5YWxpYXNpc3RoZWJlc3R3b3cqweda'
var sigKey = 'a2V5YWxpYXNpc3RoZWJlc3R3b3cqwedaa2V5YWxpYXNpc3RoZWJlc3R3b3cqweda'

that error is gone, but it return error :

"Error: options.encryptionKey must be a a 32 byte base64 string"

this make me confused because that encKey is already 32 Byte.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Your original error is because `process.env.SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING` and `process.env.SOME_64BYTE_BASE64_STRING` is not set.

Your second error is because
    `var encKey = 'a2V5YWxpYXNpc3RoZWJlc3R3b3cqweda'` and `var sigKey = 'a2V5YWxpYXNpc3RoZWJlc3R3b3cqwedaa2V5YWxpYXNpc3RoZWJlc3R3b3cqweda'`

is not valid 32BYTE_BASE64_STRING and 64BYTE_BASE64_STRING respectively.

To generate valid strings, you can use crypto module:

```
//32 bytes
require('crypto').randomBytes(32, function(err, buffer) {
    var token = buffer.toString('base64');
});

//64 bytes
require('crypto').randomBytes(64, function(err, buffer) {
    var token = buffer.toString('base64');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you haven't installed the `.env` package of npm.
you should first install the `dotenv` package and require it in your app.js at the beginning

1. `npm install dotenv`
2. `require('dotenv').config();`

Now you can custom keys in your .env file.

E.g

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing but your javascript file should be presented along with .env file you create.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For local testing (**do not commit to git**), you need to pass in a variable:

```
var encKey = "Thisisa32bytebasestring";
var sigKey = "Thisisa64bytebasestring";
```

For remote commit, you need to pass a String variable for `SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING` and `SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING` in the `.env` file:

```
var encKey = process.env.SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING
var sigKey = process.env.SOME_64BYTE_BASE64_STRING
```

You `.env` file should contain:

```
SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING=Thisisa32bytebasestring
SOME_64BYTE_BASE64_STRING=Thisisa64bytebasestring
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you havent installed .env package of npm.
you should first install the dotenv package and require it in your app.js at the beginning

1. npm install dotenv  // in terminal
2. require('dotenv').config();  // top of app.js

Answer (score 0):

1. Install dotenv via npm :-

   ```
   npm i dotenv
   ```
2. Require it in .js file :-

   ```
   require('dotenv').config();
   ```
3. create .env file in your project folder:-
4. Paste below text in .env file:-

   ```
   SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING=Thisisa32bytebasestring
   ```
5. write below code in .js file above mongoose.model() and eplace encryptingItem with your item :-

   ```
   var secret = process.env.SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING;
   userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret ,  encryptedFields: ['encryptingItem']});
   ```

Answer (score 0):

check your required name variables:
like:
It should be exactly like this:

```
const encrypt = require("mongoose-encryption");
```

So that it matches with the name:

```
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret });
```

Your const **encrypt** name should match userSchema.plugin(**encrypt**, {}..) here
I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable called `secret = "set it to any string you want"`
then you can add `{secret:secret}` to your `UserSchema.plugin();`

You can find this in the `mongoose-encryption` package docs

Answer (score 0):

In your `.env` file, ensure that the values of `SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING` and `SOME_64BYTE_BASE64_STRING` are enclosed inside a `""`

For example:

```
SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING="ThisIsMyLittlesecret"
```

Answer (score 0):

First you delete last 3 line then go with this

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
});

const secret = "ILoveMyCountryVeryMuch";
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret, encryptedFields: ['password'] });

const User = mongoose. Model("User", userSchema);
```

You can encrypt by using this code.

Answer (score 0):

In My case i was using ES6 version meaning when i was using import statement to import module which i think is not compatible with This mongoose-encryption when i turned everything to a format like

require()

everything just worked fine . And one more thing use it at the top of your .js file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).